# Hash based Akka Routing

Tags: akka

I have a stream of JSON encoded messages and I want to distribute them to group of actors or actor systems based on the field inside a message so say more like hash(key)->Actor but when the Actor dies I want to be able to hash the key to a different Actor that are available but at any given the hash of the key should always go to same Actor. Please let me know how I can achieve this with Akka?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wan to try 
ConsistentHashingPool and ConsistentHashingGroup
The ConsistentHashingPool. It uses consistent hashing to select a routee based on the sent message.

more details here http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#ConsistentHashingPool_and_ConsistentHashingGroup